# Autoplay en Iframe

Tags: javascript, html5

estoy montando una radio online. 
El panel, tiene un reproductor, que trae toda la informacion.
El problema esque no tiene Autoplay y no se como hacer para que funcione.

```
<iframe src="http://54.38.188.188/public/plataoplomoradio/embed" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100%; min-height: 150px; border: 0;"></iframe>
```

Alguien sabe como hacer para que funcione el autoplay?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En el código de éste link, http://54.38.188.188/public/plataoplomoradio/embed , debe agregar.
1. un ID

```
<i aria-hidden="true" id="btnPlay" class="material-icons lg">play_circle_filled</i>
```

2. agregar éste script antes del `</body>`

   $("#btnPlay").click();